# What could be wrong or incorrect with this function?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a local variable’s memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

```
double* weird( double a, double b )
{ 
    double c;
    c = pow( a + b, 0.5 );
    return &c;
}
```

It might be trivial for most of you guys, but I don't see what could go wrong here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is **very** wrong because you are returning a pointer to a local variable.

When `&c` gets returned, the variable `c` whose scope is the function `weird` will be destroyed, thus giving you a pointer that points to a random area in your memory.
This is **undefined behaviour**.

Comment: Returning a pointer is not undefined behaviour actually. Dereferencing that pointer will be UB.

Answer (score 2):

You declare a local variable `c` in scope of the function, that variable is not valid any more after you exit the function, so the pointer to that variable doesn't mean anything afterwards.

Comment: I understand, but if i use it like this: cout << *weird(2.1,0.2); I get the result, how can that be?

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything can happen.

Comment: @CloneXpert That code (like many other things which appear to work) causes undefined behavior. That means: Anything can happen, including the results you expect. But it can, and often will, also fail catastrophically. (In this case, it probably "works" because you did not call another function in between and thus that piece of memory wasn't overwritten so far.)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said.

variables except `static` declared in a method or between curly braces`{}` have local scope.As soon as you get out of it, the variables are destroyed..

If you still want it,use static

```
static double c;
```